# Must char16_t strings use UTF-16 encoding?

Tags: c++, c++11, encoding, utf-8

I've been digging the specification for a while now and cannot find any conclusive clauses to support either yes/no.

Does the following statement:

```
char16_t *s = u"asdf";
```

imply/enforce that the string literal "asdf" must be encoded in UTF-16?

From all I can deduce, it's a yes.

However, in this proposal [n2018](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2006/n2018.html) it says only when "`__STDC_UTF_16__`" is defined that `char16_t` literals are UTF-16 encoded, so that leaves open the door that when "`__STDC_UTF_16__`" is undefined, `char16_t` literals can be encoded anyway the compiler wants.

After all, the standard only guarantees the size, signed-ness and underlying representation of `char16_t`, it mentions nothing about how a compiler must encode a `char16_t` literal or string literal.

In the spec, it says

> The size of a `char16_t` string literal is the total number of escape
>   sequences, universal-character-names, and other characters, plus one
>   for each character requiring a surrogate pair, plus one for the
>   terminating u’\0’. [Note: The size of a `char16_t` string literal is
>   the number of code units, not the number of characters. —end note ]

This seems to mean that it is implicitly assumed that `char16_t` string literals are UTF16 encoded because "surrogate pair" is a UTF-16 concept.

Let me know if there's anything vague in the question.

Answer (score 7):

The `__STDC_UTF_16__` bits did not make it into the standard text. That is in the proposal probably because it was taken from a similar proposal for the C language. The C++ standard simply removed any and all of this nonsense and made it UTF-16 or GTFO.

Comment: Is there an authoritative source on the _GTFO_ specification? Or is that non-normative?

Comment: §1.1/1 [intro.scope]: "This International Standard specifies requirements for implementations of the C++ programming language.
The first such requirement is that they implement the language, and so this International Standard also defines C++. Other requirements and relaxations of the first requirement appear at various places within this International Standard."

Answer (score 6):

The standard is technically unconcerned with the underlying encoding, and specifies only that the value of a single `char16_t` must correspond to a UCS codepoint in the range 0~0xFFFF

§ 2.14.3

> 2 A character literal that begins with the letter u, such as u’y’, is a
>   character literal of type char16_t. The value of a char16_t literal
>   containing a single c-char is equal to its ISO 10646 code point value,
>   provided that the code point is representable with a single 16-bit
>   code unit.

Strings on the other hand can include surrogate pairs

§ 2.14.5

> 10 A string literal that begins with u, such as u"asdf", is a char16_t
>   string literal. A char16_t string literal has type “array of n const
>   char16_t”, where n is the size of the string as defined below; it has
>   static storage duration and is initialized with the given characters.
>   A single c-char may produce more than one char16_t character in the
>   form of surrogate pairs.

Only UTF-16 meets both of these requirements, although the standard leaves the door open for future compatible encodings, however unlikely that may be.